Correct term for the question as many possible answers
I'm trying to think of a word. So my brother does things without thinking and I try to think of everything that could happen as a result of that decision. Almost a chain effect result. But I can't think of the right term. Its definition is probably close to that of "over analyzing" but that's not the term I'm thinking of. Any ideas?

analysis paralysis?

Ask your brother - he'll give you an answer right away.  More seriously, perhaps explain a bit the feeling you are trying to evoke - is your brother intemperate, quick-thinking, decisive, thoughtless?  Are you considerate, analytical, or perhaps just slow?

An unpredictable outcome.

If you are looking to describe your brother's behavior, reckless, foolhardy, or impulsive might apply.
If you're looking to describe your response to someone behaving this way, consider circumspect, calculated, pragmatic, or cognizant.


Its definition is probably close to that of "over analyzing"

Being concerned for your brother is admirable. However, if you feel you are overly preoccupied with your brother's impetuous actions, you might call yourself a worrywart.
worrywart (n.)

A person who is inclined to worry unduly
M-W


One who worries excessively and needlessly.
ahd


A person who tends to worry habitually and often needlessly;
pessimist; fussbudget.
dictionary.com



There is legitimate worry and useless worry. The type of worrying I'm
referring to here is useless worry, a constant, over-the-top worrying
that usually comes from fear...Are you a worrywart? How much of
your day is consumed by worry? What is it that you fear? Are you
worried that somebody you care for will do something stupid and get
hurt or get into trouble?
Janet Hume Cox; In Service to Your
Community (2019)

